# Flutter - Is hero Animation memory intensive?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am building an App that has lots of hero animations (Including Navigating from dynamic List data). So far, I haven't seen much difference running it from my AVD. But is this a bad idea ?

Comment: Memory wise, I don't think so. But check your CPU/GPU

Comment: Activate the [performance overlay](https://flutter.io/ui-performance/#the-performance-overlay) and track the stats while your hero animations are running.